# Остановить регекс на первом совпадении

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть регекс `/\[(.{1,255})\]/g` и строка `[abc]def[xyz]`. Мне бы хотелось чтобы регекс вернул `[abc]` и `[xyz]`, но выходит `[abc]def[xyz]`. ЧЯДНТ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [ленивую квантификацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.96.D0.B0.D0.B4.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.B8_.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B2.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.BA.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.84.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F) таким образом

```
/\[(.{1,255}?)\]/g
```